# Erro Msg 207, Level 16, State 1 e Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1

Tags: sql, procedure, syntax-error, binding

Quando tento executar a seguinte consulta, aparecem-me estes dois erros:

> - Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure V_RECLAMACOES, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]Invalid column name 'Motivo'.
> - Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 43 Could not use view or function 'dbo.V_RECLAMACOES' because of binding errors.

O meu código é este, e também indiquei onde se encontram os erros:

```
use SAM_GestaoReclamacoes

declare  @DESTINATARIOS nVARCHAR(max) = NULL, -- 1º erro
  @tipo varchar(55) = NULL,
  @diaBase date = NULL,
  @ATUALIZAR_DADOS BIT = 0

declare @d date = dateadd(d, -4, getdate())

set @DESTINATARIOS = 'vitor.rodrigues@samsys.pt'
set @tipo = 'Mensal'
set @diaBase = @d


IF @DESTINATARIOS IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @DESTINATARIOS = 'Samsys@samsys.pt'
END

IF @tipo IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @tipo = 'Mensal'
END

IF @diaBase IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @diaBase = GETDATE()
END

IF @ATUALIZAR_DADOS IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ATUALIZAR_DADOS = 0
END

SET LANGUAGE Portuguese

IF @ATUALIZAR_DADOS = 1
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE SAM_GestaoReclamacoes

    SELECT *
    INTO SAM_GestaoReclamacoes
    FROM dbo.V_RECLAMACOES -- 2º erro
END

declare @top10reclamacoes varchar(max)
declare @html varchar(max)
declare @numero_reclamacoes_abertas_mes integer 
declare @numero_reclamacoes_fechadas_mes integer
declare @startofcurrentmonth datetime
declare @dataini datetime


SELECT @numero_reclamacoes_abertas_mes = count(*)
FROM Reclamacoes R
WHERE R.Data >= DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)


set @html = '<html>
<body>
<font face="verdana" size="6"><b><u><center>INFORMAÇÃO PARA TODA A EMPRESA</center></u></b></font><br>
<br>
<font face ="verdana "size="5"><b><center>Número reclamações abertas este mês:' + convert(varchar(50), @numero_reclamacoes_abertas_mes)

SELECT @numero_reclamacoes_fechadas_mes = count(*)
FROM Reclamacoes R
WHERE R.DataConclusao >= DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)
And Tratado = 1

set @html = @html + '<br><br>Número reclamações fechadas este mês:' + convert(varchar(50), @numero_reclamacoes_fechadas_mes)

Select top 10 @html = @html + '<tr><td>' + convert(nvarchar(50), ID) + '</td><td>' + convert(char(10), R.Data)  + '</td><td>' + ISNULL(convert(char(10),DataConclusao) , '') + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(max), Exposicao) + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(50), Tratado) + '</td></tr>' 
From Reclamacoes R 
Order by R.Data ASC


set @html = @html + '</html></table>'


print @html
```

Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Acho que algo não está bem na própria _VIEW_. Já validou se efetivamente a coluna `Motivo` existe na _VIEW_ `V_RECLAMACOES`?

Comment: Não consigo ter acesso à view, mas consigo ter acesso à coluna chamada também reclamações, e lá não tem uma coluna chamada Motivo mas sim IDMotivo.

Comment: Então a _VIEW_ é que deverá ser o centro do problema. Se não tiver acesso a ela não vai, com certeza, conseguir resolvê-lo.

Comment: Agradeço então a sua ajuda @JoãoMartins . Vou tentar falar com alguém superior a ver se seleciono este problema. Vlw

Comment: @JoãoMartins, também imaginei que pudesse ser problema de permissão, talvez isso resolva o segundo erro da **linha 43**. Só não sei o que pode ter causado o erro na **linha 3**.

Comment: @AndréFilipe Pois, esse erro da linha 43 consegui entender, agora o erro da linha 3 não estou mesmo a perceber o que possa ser.

Comment: Provavelmente você esteja usando alguma coluna que não existe, ou que sua escrita esteja incorreta...

Comment: @AndréFilipe já consegui solucionar os dois problemas, os problemas estavam na view da tabela.

Comment: Quais eram os problemas na **view**?

Comment: de algum jeito a coluna motivo não estava bem "conectada", o inner join nos dois queries não tinham sido bem feitos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, só foi preciso fazer esses dois passos, da seguinte maneira:
- Juntar a tabela Motivos à tabela Reclamações.

```
Inner Join Motivos M on R.IDMotivo = M.Id
```

- E no design da view adicionar também este código:
  No Select:

  dbo.Motivos.Nome

No Inner Join:
     INNER JOIN dbo.Motivos ON dbo.Reclamacoes.IdMotivo = dbo.Motivos.Id